# Is TIdAntiFreeze being deprecated in XE7?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, indy, delphi-xe7

I'm creating my very first application using XE7 and FMX to run on iOS and Android. As soon as I dropped a `TIdAntiFreeze` on my data module, my application couldn't be compiled anymore because `Vcl.IdAntiFreeze` is not part of either iOS or Android library. I tried to create the component at run-time by using the source code of `Vcl.IdAntiFreeze`, but there is no `TIdAntiFreeze.Process` implementation available for iOS or Android. At the end, I had to create a new descendant of `TIdAntiFreezeBase` like this:

```
unit uAntiFreeze;

interface

uses
  IdAntiFreezeBase;

type
  TIdAntiFreeze = class(TIdAntiFreezeBase)
  public
    procedure Process; override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  FMX.Forms;

procedure TIdAntiFreeze.Process;
begin
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

end.
```

My question is, is there something I'm missing? There seems to be extensive work done on Indy to make it work on all platforms XE7 can compile and link for. Have they forgotten `TIdAntiFreeze`?

Comment: VCL is for Windows. You are using FMX.

Comment: That component has always been a crutch. Do your Indy operations in separate threads and you won't need that component anymore because your main thread won't be blocked.

Comment: Yes. You're missing that VCL is Windows only, and therefore can't be used on iOS, OS X, and Android. (TIdAntifreeze has been discouraged for years in favor of using a separate thread, anyway.)

Comment: @KenWhite I know VCL is Windows Only. But `IdAntiFreezeBase` can be used on iOS, OS X and Android. The fact that doing network communication in the main thread is a bad idea... I completely agree. What I couldn't understand was why is `TIdAntiFreeze` not updated to support all of `FMX` targets, while `TIdAntiFreezeBase` is.

Comment: I've never had to use the Anti-Freeze because I always design my communication layer inside of a thread.

Comment: Turns out there's an `FMX.IdAntiFreeze.pas`, in the `$(BDS)\source\Property Editors\Indy10` folder, so there is a FireMonkey version of it available.  (I found it the same way I found `VCL.IdAntiFreeze.pas`, by searching my computer to see if the file existed.) I can't explain why it's not on the component palette, though.

Comment: `TIdAntiFreeze` is not deprecated (yet), but it is intentionally and explicitly filtered out of the Palette in FireMonkey. It is implemented in a *design-time* package instead of a *run-time* package (a flaw that has not be fixed yet) and thus causes problems for the IDE. That being said, mobile platforms are very sensitive to the main UI thread being blocked for any reason, even the slightest blockage can cause the OS to kill the app immediately. So just don't do it at all, use worker threads instead. Thus there is never a good reason to ever need to use `TIdAntiFreeze` on a mobile platform.